# Monad's associativity rule in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, associativity

`(m >>= f) >>= g`  =  `m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)`

what's different from `f` and `\x->f x` ??

I think they're the same type `a -> m b`. but it seems that the second `>>=` at right side of equation treats the type of `\x->f x` as `m b`.
what's going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The expressions `f` and `\x -> f x` do, for most purposes, mean the same thing. However, the scope of a lambda expression extends as far to the right as possible, i.e. `m >>= (\x -> (f x >>= g))`.

If the types are `m :: m a`, `f :: a -> m b`, and `g :: b -> m c`, then on the left we have `(m >>= f) :: m b`, and on the right we have `(\x -> f x >>= g) :: a -> m c`.

So, the difference between the two expressions is just which order the `(>>=)` operations are performed, much like the expressions `1 + (2 + 3)` and `(1 + 2) + 3` differ only in the order in which the additions are performed.

The monad laws require that, like addition, the answer should be the same for both.

Comment: Just a comment: `\x -> f x >>= g` is the same as `f >=> g`. (Kleisli fish)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Quite so! And to my eye, the relevant equivalence is considerably more elegant written that way.

Comment: In fact, the Typeclassopedia argues that this law is more elegantly stated in terms of `(>=>)`, recalling that that's basically composition. I as a learner agree.

Comment: @delnan: I'd sooner write them all that way; they're monoid laws with `(<=<)` as the operator and `return` as the identity, after all, so might as well make that obvious.

Comment: is this property associate to laziness? or just a exception?

Comment: where's (<=<) and (>=>) ? 
i tried.but both (<=<) and (>=>) are not in scope

Comment: @user20100: Not *inherently*, no. It's just a property, part of the definition of a monad, just as the associative property comes from the definition of addition. That said, laziness makes it much *easier* to define simple equivalences between expressions, which is why such properties aren't seen as often outside Haskell.

Comment: @user20100: [See here for the definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) of those operators. Import `Control.Monad` if you want them. As for what they do, see FUZxxl's comment; that's all there is to it. `(<=<)` is the same, just reversing the arguments.

Comment: @C. A. McCann: sorry for making misunderstanding.

what property I said is "the second **>>=** at right side of equation treats the type of **\x->f x** as **m b**".

in other words, does laziness make this **(\x -> f x >>= g) :: a -> m c** or not?

Comment: @user20100: It's how the syntax of Haskell works, that's all. Everything inside the parentheses is part of the lambda expression, not just the `f x`. The expression `\x -> f x` isn't relevant here because that's not how the compiler breaks the whole thing apart.

Comment: Using `>=>` or `<=<` requires that you have enabled the `-XChristianity` GHC extension.